# Spring boot - Loading configuration property file in to java.util.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to load a configuration property fully into java.util.Properties file in my spring boot project and then need to pass this wherever needed. With Spring boot I can load the full file and can get the access of the values though keys. But how I can load the whole configuration file into Properties object or pass the spring loaded property (not a single value rather all the values) wherever required?

My current code:

```
Properties myProps= new Properties();
myProps.load(resourceAsStream);
```

Comment: You can use the `PropertiesLoaderUtils` to benefit from the Spring Resource abstraction to load it but else that is the way to load properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for specific ways of loading them using Spring-boot I'd suggest looking into:

- [Binding properties to an object](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties) by using the `@Configuration`, `@ConfigurationProperties` and `@PropertySource` annotations if you want to enforce and implicitly manage type-safety at all times
- The `Environment` interface you can `@AutoWire` to your classes, if you don't need to enforce type-safety at all times (you can still do it, but you're not forced to). `@PropertySource` can be used in this case as well to load properties outside the default default-loaded `application.properties`, although they'll be loaded only when the application context refreshes (e.g. they won't be available while the application is booting up)
- The `PropertiesLoaderUtils` class, as suggested in the comments, if you want to selectively load a configuration file at runtime for example

I usually recommend the first. The result is the same as using an `@AutoWired Environment`, with the advantages of implicit type-safety and improved readability. You can then get the properties and write them inside your `java.util.properties` if you need them to be there.

However, there is more than one way to do that, both using Spring-Boot or not. Loading properties like that is also perfectly fine, although arguably not the best practice since you're using Spring-boot.